# New position of added item

Tags: angularjs, gridster

How can i retrieve the new `col` and `row` position right after adding item with `push(item)`?

When i add item, the `col` and `row` are `undefined`, and at this time i need record the right positions on DB.
I tried the 'gridster-item-initialized' event, but i'm getting `null`.
Watching the `col` and `row` vars on item controller is the only aproach that worked , but seems to be like a hack.

An 'added-item' event with new the positions or even a `addItem()` function would be interesting in this case.